# How to get the row number of the second (or the last) occurence of a word in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying some content from a webpage in an excel sheet, and searching for a particular word and then fetching the row number of the record. The copied content is from an HTML page and is pasted in a table format in excel. At times, the word is mentioned twice in the table and I want to get the row number of the record which is in the last. I have code for getting the row number at the first time, but I am not able to figure out the row number of the last record. When I am fetching the row number value, in the variable "row_no", then I need the row number of the record which is displayed in last. How can I get that? 
Please find below the code which I have written:

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
            ie.Visible = True
            ws.Activate
strHTML = URL
            ie.navigate strHTML
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4
                DoEvents
            Loop

            Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
            Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

            Set tables = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("Table")

            msg = ie.document.Body.innerHTML

              If InStr(msg, "Word1") = 0 Then
            Else
               For x = 0 To tables.Length

                        If tables(x).innerText Like "*Word1*" Then
                         found = True

                         If x > 0 Then
                         Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
                         clipboard.SetText tables(x).outerHTML
                         clipboard.PutInClipboard
                         ws.Activate
                         ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
                         Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E2:E10000"), "End Analysis")
                         MsgBox Result
                         If Result> 1 Then
'get the row number                            
                          row_no = Worksheets("temp").Range("E2:E10000").Find("End Analysis", lookat:=xlWhole).Row
                         End If
                         End If
                    Next x
                 End If
```

Comment: I'm curious - What's the overall result of what you're doing? Do you need to paste it all in to excel? Can't you connect and parse the data using MSXML2 as a background task without using IE? If you're only extracting one or two things maybe even just use an `InStrRev()` function on the text which finds the last instance of a word.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim found As Range
    With Worksheets("temp").Range("E2:E10000")
       Set found = .Find(what:="End Analysis", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
       If Not found Is Nothing Then Debug.Print found.Row
    End With
End Sub
```

Which looking like yours would be more:

```
Dim found As Range, row_no As Long
If Result > 1 Then
   Set found = Worksheets("temp").Range("E2:E10000").Find(what:="End Analysis", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
   If Not found Is Nothing Then 
       row_no = found.Row
   Else
      MsgBox "Not Found"
   End If
End If
```